# Firefox css display issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, polymer

I'm currently making a website using polymer elements like `code-header-panel`, `paper-tabs` etc.

I have multiple `<section>` tags in my markup which I want to display and hide on specific `paper-tab` clicks.

My HTML markup for the tabs:

```
<paper-tabs selected="0">
        <paper-tab id="name" name="home">Home</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab id="about" name="about">About IEEE</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab id="sbm" name="sbm">IEEE SBM</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab id="committee" name="committee">Committee</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab id="contact" name="contact">Contact Us</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
section#about{
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

And this is my Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = "";

    var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');

    tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
        a = this.selected;
        //console.log("Selected: " + tabs.selected);

        if(!e.detail.isSelected){$("section").fadeOut();}
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("section#"+a).fadeIn();
        }, 500);
    }); 
})
```

Now, this code works fine when I test it on my Chromium browser. On clicking the **about** tab, the **home** fades out and the **about** page fades in. But this does not work in Firefox at all. The **homepage** section fades out but the **about** does not show whatsoever.

I've tried `.fadeIn()`, `.show()`, `.addClass()` but to no avail. What should I do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: id can only be used once, here i understand we have : paper-tab and section sharing the same single id , how's that possible ? can you set up a codepen or jsfiddle, curious to see it happening in chrome ;)

Comment: Thank you @GCyrillus. It was quite a noob mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. My mistake was the face that my `paper-tab` elements and the `section` elements had the same ID name. Changed all ids of the `section`s to classes and it worked. Sorry for the rookie mistake.